# Create a shower hose with correct physics

Tags: physics, collision, soft-body

I'm making a shower hose that follows the handle when it moves.

I've created it successfully following [THIS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98438/56166) tutorial, but the hose is too "elasticy". I'm wondering which settings I should change (from the tutorial) to make it more rigid.

I also want it to have less "bending points" when it's moved, it should really only have one *major* curve like shower hoses do when you move them around.

Cheers.

Comment: For less elasticity you can increase the Soft Body Edge ‘pull’ strength. This will reduce the amount that each edge is able to stretch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the Softbody Simulation won't give you enough control over the movement. Here is an alternate method using a rigid body simulation.

[image]
<sup>*The flickering is caused by the gif compression and not by a simulation error artefact.*</sup>

[image]

It uses a chain of rigid bodies like in [lemon's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61415/30849).

1. Enable the [rigid body world](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/world.html#rigid-body-world).
   [image]
2. Add a cylinder, make it a cylindrical [rigid body](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/properties.html#rigid-body). Then duplicate it. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
   [image]
3. Create an empty and place it inbetween the cylinder rigid bodies. Make it a [rigid body constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/constraints/index.html#rigid-body-constraints). Set the type to **[Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/constraints/types/point.html#point)** and select the two cylinders.
   [image]
4. Create another rigid body constraint (on another empty): a **[generic spring](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/constraints/types/generic_spring.html#generic-spring)**. Enable the springs you need. I would use a very high rotation damping value, since a hose wouldn't wobble around. [0.9999]
   I parented the generic spring constraint to the first point constraint, and the point constraint to the first cylinder, but this is just for easier visualization. The point constraint acts like a spherical joint between the two cylinder and the spring pushes the cylinder back to their original positions, ensuring minimal bending.
   [image]
5. Create more cylinders, constraint and chain them. They're now ready to be simulated.
   [image]
   <sup>*Note, how the twisting of a single joint in the chain influences its surrounding joints.*</sup>
6. You can now transfer with movement to an armature with [Copy Transforms constraints](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/transform/copy_transforms.html#copy-transforms-constraint).
   [image]
7. You can also connect it to a curve using many [hook modifiers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html#hook-modifier). The drawback of this method is, that the rotation of the rigid bodies is not used.
   [image]