# Soft body for hair, how can I animate it?

Tags: animation, rigging, parent, hair, soft-body

My goal is to make my hair move like a real hair does (to have a follow through and overlap action)

I tried to use soft body for hair but its not working. I don't know what I need to parent with what.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see the lattice fell down when I tried to play the animation. What should I do? And where do I need to parent my lattice, to my rig (the controller only, not the bone) or to the hair?

Also, I parented my hair to my rig with automatic weight. Should I not do that? Because that way my hair already has the weight from the rig, right? So how do I parent my hair? Do I parent it to my rig with object (keep transform) or what?

Comment: I have been creating similiar rigs lately. I use lots of [rigid body chains](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109453/30849) and snap the bones to them. My hair is not as detailed though and I get away with 5-8 chains. You can use a collision for the head as well, hence the strands don't intersect anywhere. It his approach clear to you or do you require an answer?

Comment: It's best to use cloth simulation for hair, because it does not stretch as softbody does and has less pieces than rigid bodies. Use a low-poly simulation mesh, constrain bones to it's vertices(location of bone, track to for bone direction and last for bone roll), and with bones drive your high-poly hair.

Comment: so what should i do? it seems like if i use cloth  my hair is not working.

and the rigid body is in physic tab too right? i never knew how to use it

Comment: https://youtu.be/HCqSsB1aJso is it how it work? so i need to make bone for each poly of my hair strand?