# Dynamic cord for real time simulation [Blender -> Unity question]

Tags: animation, rigging, rigid-body-simulation, unity

I have a mechanical arm model with animations that I export to unity for a simulation game.
Now I need to add some cables and wires that move realistically with the robotic arm. Something like this just to demonstrate-
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=7&v=QtVQ-NSms2A

How should I approach this solution? 
Thanks.

Comment: Relate. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109448/create-a-shower-hose-with-correct-physics/109453#109453

Comment: Hi Leander! Will it work in Unity though?

Comment: You'll have to bake it to bones before exporting it.

Comment: As in baking the animations? Not sure what that means bake it to bones. Is there a realtime solution to it?

Comment: Yes as in baking the animations if your going to export animations anyway, if you want a realtime simulation in Unity, then this question is not about Blender.

Comment: Leander, Can you get on discord?