# Soft body control rope

Tags: animation, rigging, soft-body

Making a whip, I've used the soft body, collision and various other options. Rigged the body and the hilt of the whip to the hand. As the hand moves, the soft body rope moves, but it does not move with precision I'd like. When adding a hook to it, I get a sharp L shape. Without the hook, the rope doesn't have the correct flow as a whip should have. Some advice would be appreciated. Here's examples.

[image: without hook]

[image: with hook]

Comment: A cloth is not always the best solution for a rope, maybe you want to try [rigid bodies](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109453/30849).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/are-curve-physics-possible

Comment: Leander, I was using a soft bodie, not a cloth. I will try the rigid body though.