# Soft body and dynamic vertex weights

Tags: cloth-simulation, vertex-groups, soft-body, vertex-weights, dynamic

I want to simulate a rope using Softbody modifier(because cloth can't collide without edges) and I also want to make dynamic pinning/unpinning from the Emptys.

I can use Cloth and Vertex Weight Mix to achieve necessary result but without collision. Using Softbody gives me collision but I can't use Vertex Weight Mix because Softbody requires original data.

At the image below I want the vertex to detach at one frame and reattach at other frame.[image]

Like this
[image]

Comment: I don't know if this will help you - the rope falling across the rock is what I have in mind. (4th clip) Either end and mid sections can be handled any way you wish.  It used physics to fall and collide and then manually bounced at the ends -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226766/how-do-i-pin-a-ball-to-a-cloth-sim-rope-to-create-wrecking-ball/227382#227382

I can dig out the Blend file if you think you can use it.