# Cell fracture issue (missing pieces)

Tags: cell-fracture

As you can see in the link, my cell fracture isn't working correctly. The bust sculpt had a lot of subdivisions so i started to add an decimate modifier. But when i added the cell fracture it is missing pieces. I also tried to ad a solidify modifier first but that also doesn't work. In the pictures you can also see the settings of the cell fracture. if you know to solve this with the right settings let me know :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd0b2.jpg

Comment: You can reduce the number of segments by reducing the "Source Limit" value in the CF panel. (in earlier versions that's just under the "Own Vertices" button at top left)  As far as coping with missing bits and extruding extras, you can conceal these by substituting the CF'd segments with a copy of the original, scaled up a little.  (switch the CF'd version to invisible until the fracturing is to take place.  When it does, visually switch back to the CF'd model.

Comment: PS to the above...  The 1st video clip at the link below uses the original model to hide the Cell Fractured one until the impact point.

Link - 

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226766/how-do-i-pin-a-ball-to-a-cloth-sim-rope-to-create-wrecking-ball/227382#227382