# Rigid bodies not working correctly

Tags: modeling, mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

so im trying to make a dangling chain with rigid body physics in blender.

Heres the problem:

[image]

I added a rigid body to the first chain as a constraint so it will be able to dangle. As you can see I turned off dynamic so it will be static.

[image]

And the other chains have rigid body with dynamic enabled.

But when I press play:

[image]

Everything explodes.
I dont know why this is happening, if someone could help it would mean a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have scale applied on all rigid bodies?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Blender's physics is great for impacts and bounces etc, but can be a bit of a mind bender in cases such as yours.  If all you want to do is show a chain dangling or swinging you might consider doing it this way - (see section on swinging chain)

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226766/how-do-i-pin-a-ball-to-a-cloth-sim-rope-to-create-wrecking-ball/227382#227382