# Animate sphere pulled by chain

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I wanted to animate a ghost that pulls a chain with a metal ball behind itself (like the typical comic prisoner).

The problem is that I couldn't find a way to even get remotely close to what I want. I want the chain to be attached to a point that I can move around with keyframes on one end and to the ball on the other end. The ball collides with the ground and ideally also poses some resistance to getting dragged along.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: maybe you should google or search here...so you will find a lot of answers like this so you will get a starting point https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7280/reel-in-anchor-using-physics/7286#7286

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226766/how-do-i-pin-a-ball-to-a-cloth-sim-rope-to-create-wrecking-ball/