# How do you animate a rope?

Tags: animation

Just curious. I'm not at this stage yet but I'd like to know what to expect. I'm working on an animated short film that involves a claw machine, and when the claw drops, the rope (chord, line, whatever you want to call it) holding it will have to extend. Anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Hi, I edited your post and remove the question about 'best way', because that calls for an opinion, and opinion answers aren't allowed here.

Comment: Can't find the answer I had in mind, specifically for rope.  These two might help though...


Guillotine -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194833/rope-simulation-using-rigid-bodies/195841#195841

Weight on a swinging chain -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209434/rigid-body-physics-cant-transform-or-move-mesh-when-applied/209868#209868

Comment: Related: [How to simulate a rope?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope)

Comment: How much work might depend on a couple of details: Does the rope ever go slack? Does it have to coil? Does it have a visible texture, or is it smooth?

Comment: Well the rope attached to the claw usually doesn't have slack it just kinda comes straight down. I think the guillotine example is the most similar so thanks Edgel3D